# strange variable scope in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I know scope in javascript in sometimes tough but this time I suspect the issue may be jQuery execution order. In the following code I try to define a simple HTML element (simulates a button) in javascript and pass different text to it when mounting it in HTML using jQuery:

```js
var name;
var buttonsecondary = '<div class="buttonsecondary clicked"><p>'+name+'</p></div>';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-item" id="things4">
  <a href="aFabrica.html">
    <div class="itemHome">
      <div class="bg" id="buttonsecondaryfabrica"></div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var name = "A Fábrica";
          $("#buttonsecondaryfabrica").after(buttonsecondary)
        })
      </script>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="content-item">
  <a href="lojas.html">

    <div class="itemHome">
      <div class="bg" id="buttonsecondaryloja"></div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var name = "Loja";
          $("#buttonsecondaryloja").after(buttonsecondary)
        })
      </script>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The problem is that I get the same text on both buttons: "Store" although in the first alert getting "Street" and in the second "Store"...
Does anyone know how to explain it?

Comment: You may need to add the buttons to the DOM using an anonymous function.

Comment: @atmd: Or better yet, a Stack Snippet here on site.

Comment: its because you are changing `name` and `buttonsecondary` stay unchanged

Comment: try using only one $(document).ready(

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer Thanks! I was struggling to format it and gave up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `buttonsecondary` variable already contains the final HTML of the button because it's merely a concatenated string.

You need to *generate* the desired HTML each time:

```
function generateButton(name)
{
    return '<div class="buttonsecondary clicked"><p>' + name + '</p></div>';
}
```

Then:

```
var name = "A Fábrica";
$("#buttonsecondaryfabrica").after(generateButton(name));
```

And

```
var name = "Loja";
$("#buttonsecondaryloja").after(generateButton(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you are creating a string with variables that are changed later on. When you change the variables, the string does not get updated because the variables are not bound. You need to create a new string if you want to pass in a new value for the `name`.

Change this:

```
var buttonsecondary = '<div class="buttonsecondary clicked"><p>'+name+'</p></div>';
```

To this:

```
function createSecondaryButton(name) {
    return '<div class="buttonsecondary clicked"><p>' + name + '</p></div>';
}
```

---

Or, since you are using jQuery:

```
function createSecondaryButton(name) {
    return $('<div>').addClass('buttonsecondary clicked')
        .append($('<p>').text(name));
}
```

Then simply call the function:

```
$("#buttonsecondaryfabrica").after(createSecondaryButton('A Fábrica'));
$("#buttonsecondaryloja").after(createSecondaryButton('Loja'));
```